# HQL subquery in FROM clause for right join

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to perform an SQL query in the following format:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE flag=1) AS a
RIGHT JOIN TableB AS b 
ON a.refb = b
```

The idea is just to right join a subset of TableA with the full TableB. In this way, TableA rows with flag != 0 show up just once in the end result, with NULL values.

Now, I would think that the equivalent HQL query would be something similar to this:

```
FROM (FROM TableA ta WHERE ta.flag = 1) AS a
RIGHT JOIN a.bref b
```

But apparently subqueries are not supported in FROM clauses. Is there any alternative way to obtain the same result?

Comment: Just `FROM( SELECT * FROM ....)` wont do? You can use full select syntax in hql also

Comment: No other way, but execute them as native SQL queries. JPA nor Hibernate does not currently support querying from derived tables (subqueries)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, b from TableA a right join a.bref b with a.flag = 1
```

The point is to use the [`with`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins) clause which defines outer join extra conditions.

Comment: I tried to add a with clause after the join, but then I get this: org.hibernate.hql.ast.InvalidWithClauseException: with-clause expressions did not reference from-clause element to which the with-clause was associated

Comment: The query I have now (which gets me that error) is more similar to this: FROM TableA AS a RIGHT JOIN a.bref b WITH a.flag=1

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Sorry I misread the question.

You can use full select clauses on HQL, the syntax you provided is invalid because of the `FROM ( FROM`, just change it to `FROM ( SELECT * FROM` and it will work

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the same error message: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 6 [FROM (SELECT * FROM...